# Get pattern startindex with grep or similar

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm looking for a shell command to find the start index of a pattern in a text file. Indices start at 0. Example:

```
#test.txt
hello
world

# The newline character is just a normal character
$ command test.txt world
6
$ command test.txt o
4, 7
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you assume a [zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) right?

Comment: Yes, zero based numbering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) more carefully, I found the `-bo` switch for grep. I'm using GNU grep version 3.1. This did the trick for me, but may not work for UTF-* encoded files since it just shows the byte offset.

`grep -bo world test.txt`

Comment: A very nice and simple question and wonderful to see that you kept searching yourself! Maybe add some more information (quote of the manpage) to make this a bit more explanatory. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Maybe you want to combine it with `n` to get the line-number : `grep -bon world test.txt`

Comment: Just make a note that it requires `gnu grep`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
cat srch.awk
BEGIN{RS=FS=""}
{
   s=$0
   k=0
   while (n=index(s, kw)) {
      k+=n
      printf "%d ", k-1
      s=substr(s, n+length(kw))
   }
   print ""
}
```

Now use it as:

```
awk -v kw='world' -f srch.awk test.txt
6

awk -v kw='o' -f srch.awk test.txt
4 7
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='world' 'RT!=""{print sum+length()} {sum+=length($0 RT)}'  file
6
$ awk -v RS='o' 'RT!=""{print sum+length()} {sum+=length($0 RT)}'  file
4
7
```